# PowerDesigner engineering Unicode

Tags: sql-server, reverse, powerdesigner

I am using PowerDesigner to model my SQL Server database. I am creating a Physical Data Model. My problem is that comment data does show "???" instead of a text I entered.

Does anybody know how to get the root of the problem?

Comment: Where do the comment data show "???"? Do you execute the generated script, and look the comment inside SQL Server? Which character set are you using outside ASCII? May I suggest Arabic letters?

Comment: Internally PowerDesigner represent letters as UTF-16. So the problem would be with script generation. Or do you execute the script outside PowerDesigner?

Comment: in table properties it shows me "???" in comment field. I also add that this model is worked correctly and showd persian letter which we add to model in comment field.

Comment: maybe this problem is due to reverse enginieering setting

Comment: How did you reverse engineer? From script, or from database connection?...

Comment: from database connection

Comment: AND ALSO BY FILE-REVERSE ENGINNERING -DTABASE -UTF8

Comment: As I mentioned under my answer, the DBMS definition is incorrect. You could try to edit your DBMS (`Database > Edit Current DBMS`) to try it, under MSSQLSRV2016::Script\Objects\Table\TableComment for generation, and MSSQLSRV2016::Script\Objects\Table\SqlListQuery for reverse...

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer the question. I've just tried something which looks like what you mentioned in your question.

I started with a Physical Data Model (initially a Conceptual Data Model: entity Employee; Manager inherits from Employee; Manager relates to one-to-many Employee). With some persan comment (using Google Translate), initially on Manager.

[image: Initial physical model, one table with comment]

I generate the database creation script, using the UTF-8 encoding.

[image: Script generation options]

This gave me this script:

```
create or replace table EMPLOYEE 
(
   EMPID                char(10)                       not null,
   MAN_EMPID            char(10)                       null,
   constraint PK_EMPLOYEE primary key clustered (EMPID)
);
comment on table EMPLOYEE is 
'اولین و مهمترین وظیفه شما به عنوان یک رهبر مسئولیت این است که انرژی خود را به عهده بگیرید و سپس به ارکستر کردن انرژی اطرافیان کمک کنید.';
create unique clustered index EMPLOYEE_PK on EMPLOYEE (
EMPID ASC
);
create index RELATIONSHIP_1_FK on EMPLOYEE (
MAN_EMPID ASC
);
```

Then I reverse this script using `File > Reverse Engineer > Database...`, making sure to select the proper encoding:

[image]

Which retrieves the table comment:

[image]

What do you do differently?

Comment: Not the same context, but I manage to generate/reverse through ODBC connection against a SAP SQL Anywhere 17 database. And retrieve the original comment.

Comment: OK, I have the same problem when reversing from Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I see: the generated script is incorrect, it should have a N in front of the comment string. The reverse is incorrect, it should convert the comment to nvarchar (instead of varchar) to have an opportunity to retrieve it...